# Android Leak Canary Log

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am using Leaky Canary to detect memory leaks in my app. While I was able to get rid of 2-3 issues before this, I cannot figure out where the leak is from this log

```
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: In com.prism.prism:1.1:2.
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * com.prism.prism.RatePicActivity_ has leaked:
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT android.database.ContentObserver$Transport.mContentObserver
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * references android.app.Activity$SettingsObserver.this$0
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.prism.prism.RatePicActivity_ instance
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: 29bcc62a-b7e2-4d80-8cda-be2f841f19aa
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Device: samsung samsung GT-I9300 m0xx
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Android Version: 4.4.4 API: 19 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Durations: watch=5024ms, gc=176ms, heap dump=1129ms, analysis=12787ms
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Details:
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Instance of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mContentObserver = android.app.Activity$SettingsObserver [id=0x41b22d00]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mDescriptor = java.lang.String [id=0x41913c70]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mOwner = android.database.ContentObserver$Transport [id=0x41b1a878]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mObject = 1570915608
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Instance of android.app.Activity$SettingsObserver
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   this$0 = com.prism.prism.RatePicActivity_ [id=0x41ba5aa0]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler = android.os.Handler [id=0x41c45f78]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mLock = java.lang.Object [id=0x41c7c220]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mTransport = android.database.ContentObserver$Transport [id=0x41b1a878]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * Instance of com.prism.prism.RatePicActivity_
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   onViewChangedNotifier_ = org.androidannotations.api.view.OnViewChangedNotifier [id=0x41cceb68]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   application = com.prism.prism.MyApplication_ [id=0x41b26fe0]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   backgroundImageView = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView [id=0x41ba1960]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   fragment_container = android.widget.FrameLayout [id=0x41b6f098]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14 [id=0x4226a548]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mMediaController = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.FragmentController [id=0x41cd05c0]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler =     android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1 [id=0x41c63520]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mCreated = true
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mOptionsMenuInvalidated = false
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mReallyStopped = true
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mResumed = false
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mRetaining = false
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mStopped = true
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mActionBar = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo [id=0x41c6ab08]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mAllLoaderManagers = android.util.ArrayMap [id=0x41cab818]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mApplication = com.prism.prism.MyApplication_ [id=0x41b26fe0]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl [id=0x41c48e60]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow [id=0x41b966a0]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread [id=0x417e1d80]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mTranslucentCallback = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName [id=0x41c76c08]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy [id=0x41c730f8]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mContainer = android.app.Activity$1 [id=0x41cffe98]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration [id=0x41df0360]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mDecor = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mTitle = java.lang.String [id=0x41b66db8]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mDefaultKeySsb = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mSettingsObserver = android.app.Activity$SettingsObserver [id=0x41b22d00]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mSearchManager = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mEmbeddedID = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mResultData = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mParent = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mFragments = android.app.FragmentManagerImpl [id=0x41ed3590]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler = android.os.Handler [id=0x41c45f78]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mMenuInflater = null
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mImmerseModeRunnable = android.app.Activity$3 [id=0x41cebb80]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker [id=0x41cf0dc0]
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation [id=0x41b26818]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mIntent = android.content.Intent [id=0x41b19e40]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mLoaderManager = null
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mManagedDialogs = null
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread [id=0x41b16958]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList [id=0x41c6d948]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mLoadersStarted = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mIdent = 1103360840
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mFinished = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mResultCode = 0
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mResumed = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mDestroyed = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mStartedActivity = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mStopped = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mTemporaryPause = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mTitleColor = 0
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mTitleReady = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mChangingConfigurations = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mVisibleFromClient = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mVisibleFromServer = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mWindowAdded = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mCalled = true
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mBase = uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper [id=0x41c522b8]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mInflater = uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater [id=0x41df9618]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mOverrideConfiguration = null
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mResources = android.content.res.XResources [id=0x41b22d80]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme [id=0x41c48c10]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mThemeResource = 2131492994
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: |   mBase = uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper [id=0x41c522b8]
11-14 18:05:05.335 32099-3554/? E/LeakCanary: Leak result dropped because we already store 7 leak traces.
```

I am unable to tell where the memory leak is occurring in this case. Can someone point out how to go about identifying it?

Answer (score 3):

```
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * com.prism.prism.RatePicActivity_ has leaked:
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT android.database.ContentObserver$Transport.mContentObserver
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * references android.app.Activity$SettingsObserver.this$0
11-14 18:05:05.330 32099-3554/? D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.prism.prism.RatePicActivity_ instance
```

Looking at the line three in the log above, there is a reference to settings observer in the system somewhere, which in turn contains reference to the activity.

So most probably you didn't **unregister your content observer** `SettingsObserver`. Please do something like the following:

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(settingsObserverReference);
```

Here is the documentation for [ContentResolver#unregisterContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#unregisterContentObserver(android.database.ContentObserver))

Answer (score 1):

@shubham-chaudhary, and for this case?

```
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: * Instance of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   mContentObserver = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$SettingsObserver [id=0x130efea0]
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   mDescriptor = java.lang.String [id=0x7016e998]
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   mObject = -1185785128
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   mOwner = android.database.ContentObserver$Transport [id=0x13172320]
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: * Instance of com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$SettingsObserver
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   this$0 = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow [id=0x12eabf80]
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler = android.os.Handler [id=0x130efec0]
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   mLock = java.lang.Object [id=0x130f1240]
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: |   mTransport = android.database.ContentObserver$Transport [id=0x13172320]
11-19 11:22:09.513 9335-10345/lar21.pontotel D/LeakCanary: * Instance of com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow
```

Comment: Looks like a leak in android internal. I have also face similar leaks with TextSpans etc. If you can't find any similar question, please open one with the trace and someone might point you to a workaround/solution.